# Error CS5001, tutorial script fails to find entry point

Tags: c#

I'm just getting into this so forgive me for my foolishness. I was using the tutorial for the program [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/tutorial-projects-solutions?view=vs-2019)
And it informed me to type this code:

```
using System;

namespace QuickDate
{
    internal class Calendar
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime now = GetCurrentDate();
            Console.WriteLine($"Today's date is {now}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        internal static DateTime GetCurrentDate()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.Date;
        }
    }
}
```

However it just gives me the error code CS5001 saying it doesn't contain a static 'main' method for an entry point, even though it appears to have that. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you've managed to create the wrong kind of project or a project with namespaces settings that are different to what you pasted ; try starting over - I just followed that tutorial and the steps worked ok

Comment: agreed, the code you pasted in your question is working

Comment: ps; If your second attempt works you could use a diff tool to difference the two directories and see how they differ which would answer your question (and might be helpful to future readers). FWIW when you get into things in a bigger way you won't start from empty projects; you'll load a skeleton that already has all this static void main set up etc. This tutorial is just these steps with empty files to make sure you end up on the same page as the tutorial (didn't work eh?! :) )

Comment: So restarting ended up working. No idea what i did wrong but it works now

Comment: I had this problem and even clearing out the obj and bin folders didn't help. I'd have saved myself a lot of time if I'd just created a fresh project and transplanted the code across to start with.